# Avoid duplicate entry for 3 fields in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, duplicates

In my Microsoft Access 2013 database, I have 3 Call Detail areas in which I can document the outcome of calls to potential new customers. The final step in the 3 details, is an outcome displaying what the call generated. I would like to avoid the word "Booked" being duplicated in the 3 outcome fields I have.

The 3 fields I want to prevent "booked" duplication are respectively named; [outcome1],[outcome2],[outcome3]

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the schema and you can use an index constraint. The outcomes should be in a separate table related to the call table with a foreign key. Once you do that you can be sure no duplicate outcomes are tied to the same foreign key.

BTW, one outcome attribute per record. Not three attributes that mean the same thing but are named differently in one record.